# How stop horizontal scroll in rigth of div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I'm new in the code and I try to stop the horizontal scroll when the div number 2 is visible in full (so that the div 3 is not visible but aund even there).
My code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            
    $(window).scroll(function() {

    var stopScroll = $('.block-2').offset().left;
   
    if ($(window).scrollLeft() > $('.block-2').offset().left) {
        $(window).scrollLeft(stopScroll);
    }

    });
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  
  header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #252525;
    
  }
  
  .wrap {
    padding-top: 74px;
    margin: 0;
    flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
  flex-direction: row!important;
  display: flex;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 90vw;
  }
  
  .block-1,
  .block-2 {
    height: 500px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  p {
    margin-top: 185px;
  }
  
  .block-1 {
    background: #27AACC;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  
  .block-2 {
    background: #668E99;
    color: #FFF
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
        <div class="block-1">
          <div class="container">
      
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-2">
          <div class="container">
      
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="block-1">
          <div class="container">
      
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I was inspired in this forum to write this code.
I try test a lot of solution but that was not walk :(.
Do you know where i can try this ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, that it solve your issue. For jquery and pure javascript.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var wrapWidth = $('.wrap').width();
    var secondBoxWidth = $('.block-2').offset().left;
    var scrollable = $('.wrap')[0].scrollWidth;
    var breakPoint = scrollable - (wrapWidth + secondBoxWidth);

    if ($(window).scrollLeft() >= breakPoint) {
      $(window).scrollLeft(breakPoint);
      return;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-top: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #252525;
}

.wrap {
  padding-top: 74px;
  margin: 0;
  flex-wrap: nowrap!important;
  flex-direction: row!important;
  display: flex;
}

.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  width: 90vw;
}

.block-1,
.block-2 {
  height: 500px;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  margin-top: 185px;
}

.block-1 {
  background: #27AACC;
  color: #FFF;
}

.block-2 {
  background: #668E99;
  color: #FFF
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-2">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="block-1">
    <div class="container">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Pure JS solution**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const scrollFunc = () => {
  const wrap = document.querySelector('.wrap');
  const wrapWidth = document.querySelector('.wrap').offsetWidth;
  const secondBoxWidth = document.querySelector('.block-2').offsetWidth;
  const scrollable = wrap.scrollWidth;
  const start = Math.round(window.scrollX);
  const breakPoint = scrollable - (wrapWidth + secondBoxWidth);

  if (start >= breakPoint) {
     window.scrollTo(breakPoint, 0);
     return;
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunc);
});
```